# CCPanZoomController + Touchable/Clickable sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using [CCPanZoomController](https://github.com/robertblackwood/CCPanZoomController) to make my 'map' (one image) zoomable and pan-able.
On this map I would like to have clickable/touchable sprites, which when clicked change the image in the sprite.

The problem is that when the user pinches the screen (to zoom out/in), they may touch the sprite, which changes the image of the sprite, which is something I don't want.

I had an idea to solve this, but as I'm new to Cocos2d I don't know how to implement it:
I thought that I could detect when the user touches the screen/the sprite, and doesn't move their touch (as if to pinch or pan) through detecting when the user first touches the screen, (transform that initial touch into a coordinate), and then when the user stops touching the screen (turn that into a coordinate), and compare the both, and if their is no change (or very little change) then change the image of a sprite?

How would I go about doing this? Big thanks to anyone who can help!!

Answer (score 1):

So I've been working with CCPanZoomController myself in my game and ran into similar issues as you but with many different aspects such as when they touch a sprite, I didn't want to have the background move with it or I'd want the sprite to not move when the background was zooming. So what I did was to make methods to "turn off" touches for the layer that I didn't want to react and re-enable them once the action in the other layer was done.

I created the following method inside each layer to disable it or enable it for touch which I call from the different touch events.

```
// Public Method: Allows for disabling touch for this layer and re-enabling it
-(void)enableTouches:(BOOL)enable
{
    // Check if the bool value is to enable or disable touches
    if (enable) {
        // Call for the removal of all touch locations in array in the CCLayerPanZoom instance
        [_panZoomLayer removeTouchesFromArray];

        // Call the touch dispatcher and add the CCLayerPanZoom back as a delegate for touches
        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addStandardDelegate:_panZoomLayer priority:0];

        CCLOG(@"PanZoomWrapperLayer:enableTouches - LayerPanZoom touches enabled");

    } else {

        // Call the touch dispatcher to remove the CCLayerPanZoom as a delegate to disable touches
      [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:_panZoomLayer];

      CCLOG(@"PanZoomWrapperLayer:enableTouches - LayerPanZoom touches disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this isnt really what I was looking for - I may beable to use it later on in my game though!

Comment: No problem. A final note...I forgot to include the code for the method I added to the CCPanZoomController class to empty the array. It's simple but just in case, here you go.
    // Public Method: Custom method for clearing the touch array when disabling touches temporary to properly work when re-enabling.
    -(void)removeTouchesFromArray
    {
    // Removes all objects from the touch array
    [self.touches removeAllObjects];
    }

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple solution to this problem. However it may not suit your needs!

1. I've subclassed the CCMenu class and overridden the `-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` as follows:

   > -(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   >   {
   >       [_selectedItem unselected];
   >       _selectedItem = nil; 
   >   }
2. I've set the `touchSwallow` property of the instance of that new menu to `NO`.